# Positioning background static resource image

Tags: visualforce, css, static-resources

So I have a static resource which sets an image as a background image

CSS:

```
body{ background-image:url("BriefingNotes/Background-pic.jpg") }
```

VF

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.zipfile, 'customcss.css')}"/>
```

The issue I am having is with the above line in the body tags of my VF page. Half of the image displays in the bottom half of 1 page and then the rest on the top of the next page (i.e. it is placed in between 2 pages which is not what I need). I need to have it on a separate page (its own page set as a background) and then I can have other information in the subsequent pages. The background should only appear on the first page and not any other subsequent pages. I am unsure how to do so. Do I write it in my CSS file?

Comment: Are you rendering this Visualforce page as a PDF?

Comment: Sorry yes I am. I  should have mentioned that

Comment: The PDF renderer's behavior with background images is eccentric to say the least. If your background image is not full-bleed (8.5x11), you can probably get this to work using standard CSS. You may need to make the image a specific DPI (96, I think, but it might be 72). I was never able to make full bleed work, and its been a long time since I worked on it - hopefully someone will have more insight.